# bom модель в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, интересует вопрос: на каком уровне BOM модели регистрируются переменные, которые объявлены var в JS?

Comment: А что такое бом?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, [Browser Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Object_Model)

Answer (score 0):

Если следовать диаграмме в https://learn.javascript.ru/browser-environment, то `var`-переменные в браузерном окружении регистрируются не внутри BOM, a параллельно с BOM, DOM и глобальными объектами JS:

```js
var foo = 42;

console.log(window.document.URL); // DOM
console.log(window.navigator.language); // BOM
console.log(window.Infinity); // JS
console.log(window.foo); // var
```